# Typescript enum array variable

Tags: typescript, enums

Is it possible to have a string[] type variable but that allows 
only values from an enumeration ?

I am trying to achieve it this way but something is wrong:

```
enum RobotTransformType = {
 JET = "JET",
 CAR = "CAR"
 ... many other options
}

let multipleTransformBot: RobotTransformType[];
multipleTransformBot = ["JET","CAR",... maybe others];
```

It also important to know that this enumeration is the type of a Typegoose(typescript mongoose) model:

```
@prop({ enum: RobotTransformType })
transformType: RobotTransformType[];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
enum RobotTransformType  {
 JET = "JET",
 CAR = "CAR"
}

let multipleTransformBot: RobotTransformType[];
multipleTransformBot = [RobotTransformType.JET,
    RobotTransformType.CAR
];
```

Watch my lesson on string enums here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkKunJj_bZecSLIEeXEhUxD7e7aj7-fN3

Comment: I checked your channel, great work, thank you. The problem is that the RobotTransformType enumeration is type of a model property like :   class RobotTypeModel { @prop({ enum: RobotTransformType })
transformType: RobotTransformType[]; }